# Access snapshot data get from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am developing iOS project which uses Firebase database.

I have a observer to observe new data added to my Firebase database:

```
rootRef.observeEventType(.childAdded, withBlock: {(snap) in
  // I try to access "positions" like this
  if let mySnap = snap {
     let positions = mySnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "positions").value as? Array
     // But the positions is nil
})
```

The `snap` received is like this (It is `print(snap)`):

```
Optional( Snap (-KWoKFfKZOkFyoLI9at_) {
    positions =     {
        0 =         {
            x = 80;
            y = 212;
        };
        1 =         {
            x = 80;
            y = "212.5";
        };
        10 =         {
            x = 83;
            y = 229;
        }
     };
});
```

What is the right way to access "positions" data that get from firebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added response of `mySnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "positions").value` in comment it is type of `Array` of `Dictionary` so type cast it to `[[String: Any]]`.

```
let positions = mySnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "positions").value as? [[String: Any]]
```

Comment: Let's forget about sorting. I don't understand why use `Int` in `[Int : [String : Any]]`, I don't have integer key, why you suggest that in the first place? As you see in my question, the snapshot key is something like this `-KWoKFfKZOkFyoLI9at_` Could you please explain why use `Int` ?

Comment: But I already showd the whole `snapshot` in my question. It was generated from `print(snap)`

Comment: I'm taking about this `mySnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "positions").value` try to print this one without casting.

Comment: Here is it: `Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x60800005e870>(
{
    x = "105.5";
    y = 145;
},
{
    x = "105.5";
    y = "145.5";
},
{
    x = "105.5";
    y = 146;
},
{
    x = "105.5";
    y = 146;
}
)
)
`

Comment: Then your casting should work with `Array`, try once like `let positions = mySnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "positions").value as? [[String: Any]]`

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. Could you please update your answer and please explain why [[String: Any]] works, then, I will upvote & accept your answer.

Comment: @Leem.fin Edited answer but don't know why it has not works with `Array` may be you need to also specify the type of Array like Array of `Dictionary` or Array of `String` or something else.

Comment: Yep, it also works by casting to `Array<[String: Any]>`, is it so that the `x` & `y` in data is treated as `String`, that's why we use [String:Any] to represent the dictionary?

Comment: @Leem.fin `[String: Any]` means all key will be of type string, value may be string, number, object etc.